# Fit text into an EditText Android

Tags: java, android

I´m using an `EditText` to put a specific text with `editText.setText(string)`, I'm trying to match the height of `EditText` to the lines of my String, but I can´t.

If I take my `EditText` and write normal, it works well, but I need to put the text with `setText()`.

Can someone help me?

[image: example]

```
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:id="@+id/text_description"
                android:maxLength="500"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:layout_weight="0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In your XML file set the `android:layout_height` attribute to `wrap_content` like this :

```
<EditText
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   ...../>
```

Comment: @LeonardoCavani try to remove the `maxLength` attribute

Comment: and also set the weight to 1 like this `android:layout_weight="1"`

Comment: Try using a `LinearLayout` instead of a relative layout